# UI Automation + Windows Phone 8?

Tags: user-interface, windows-phone-8, automation

does UI Automation supports Windows Phone 8 or is it only for Desktop Windows?

I can't find proper info about this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm talking about this - UI Automation.

Comment: nvm, my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Between desktop Windows & Windows Phone, UIA is only supported for the desktop.